# How to remove blank spaces from a string in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have strings suppose `'1234  567890'` and `'SQL  Server'`, now i want to remove blank spaces from the strings .Anybody got any idea how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do this with REPLACE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: Does SQL Server support replace? E.g replace(column,' ','')

Comment: yes, why not??? @jarlh

Comment: @user3540365, I can't always remember which products support which functions...

Comment: yeah, it works...thanks..

Comment: yes buddy, me too. i thoughts you got any other reason. :) @jarlh

Answer (score 2):

```
select Replace('1234 567890',' ','')
```

[REPLACE (string_expression,string_pattern,string_replacement)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862(v=sql.100).aspx)